# JSLint warning in Brackets how to fix it for running javascript?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I trying to write javascript code on Brackets IDE. But it shows error every time I run the code. JSLint problem

```
console.log(a);
```

Says that 'console' was used before it was defined. console.log(a);
I do not know how to fix it. Please can somebody help me fix this issue with Brackets.

Comment: JSLint doesn't assume that `console` exists by default. You'll have to enable its [`devel` option](http://jslint.com/help.html), or "*Assume in development*," to have it recognize `console`, among others. You can also include the comment `/*global console */` at the top of the file.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Probably worth adding as an answer. The only other thing I'd add is that if you assume browser and have `window` as the global, you could go `window.console.log`, which is usually what I do with console, alert, etc., but I think it's fine as-is.

Answer (score 2):

If you use

`/*global document, window, alert, console, require*/`

at the top of your file, it fixes this issue.